# Fastest way to get data from a CSV in C++

Tags: c++, performance, csv, serialization

I have a large CSV (75 MB approximately) of this kind:

```
1,2,4
5,2,0
1,6,3
8,3,1
...
```

And I store my data with this code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    char c; // to eat the commas

    int x, y, z;
    std::vector<int> xv, yv, zv;

    std::ifstream file("data.csv");
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        std::istringstream ss(line);
        ss >> x >> c >> y >> c >> z;
        xv.push_back(x);
        yv.push_back(y);
        zv.push_back(z);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And it tooks me in this large CSV (~75MB):

```
real        0m7.389s
user        0m7.232s
sys         0m0.132s
```

That's so much!

Recently, using a Snippet of Sublime Text, I found another way to read a file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> v;

    if (FILE *fp = fopen("data.csv", "r")) {
        char buf[1024];
        while (size_t len = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fp))
            v.insert(v.end(), buf, buf + len);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

And it tooks me (without getting data) in this large CSV (~75MB):

```
real        0m0.118s
user        0m0.036s
sys         0m0.080s
```

That's a huge difference on time!

The question is how I can get the data in 3 vectors in a faster way in a vector of chars! I don't know how can I do in a faster way than the first proposed.

Thank you very much! ^^

Comment: First of all the two programs are not equivalent. Secondly, neither program actually *parses* the file correctly (the second program doesn't even attempt to get the separate values).

Comment: Try a deque instead of a vector. Also, do you have any control over the files?

Comment: I agree with Joachim Pileborg. Neither of your code does parse the CSV

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course your second version will be much faster - it merely reads the file into memory, without parsing the values in it. The equivalent of the first version using C-style I/O would be along the lines of

```
if (FILE *fp = fopen("data.csv", "r")) {
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d,%d,%d", &x, &y, &z) == 3) {
        xv.push_back(x);
        yv.push_back(y);
        zv.push_back(z);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

which, for me, is about three times faster than the C++-style version. But a C++ version without the intermediate `stringstream`

```
while (file >> x >> c >> y >> c >> z) {
    xv.push_back(x);
    yv.push_back(y);
    zv.push_back(z);
}
```

is almost as fast.

Comment: Wow! Now it tooks me only 3 seconds approximately in C++! And if I want to store C++ strings?

Comment: I'll post another question a lit difficult about getting data in C and C++. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have another question of this kind in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785538/get-a-string-in-text-csv-file-in-c. Thank you for all!

Answer (score 2):

Save in the file, how many numbers are written inside.
Then, on loading resize the vectors. It could reduce the time a bit.

Comment: 4 year old question, and no code + time results to prove you were right?  This isn't helpful.