# Get a string in text CSV file in C++

Tags: c++, performance, csv, serialization

I have a large CSV (~75 MB) of this kind:

```
1,3,4.1,5.4
-2,-4,-0.1,-11.3
...
```

And I store my data with this code **(C style)**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int s;
    int x;
    float y;
    double z;

    std::vector<int> t;
    std::vector<int> u;
    std::vector<float> v;
    std::vector<double> w;

    if (std::FILE *f = std::fopen("data.csv", "r")) {
        while (std::fscanf(f, "%d,%d,%f,%lf", &s, &x, &y, &z) == 4) {
            t.push_back(s);
            u.push_back(x);
            v.push_back(y);
            w.push_back(z);
        }
    std::fclose(f);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And it tooks me in this large CSV (~75MB):

```
real        0m3.195s
user        0m3.032s
sys         0m0.148s
```

It's so fast in C style!

Another way it's with this code **(C++ style)**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    char c; // to eat the commas. Not eat spaces :-(
    int s;
    int x;
    float y;
    double z;

    std::vector<int> t;
    std::vector<int> u;
    std::vector<float> v;
    std::vector<double> w;

    std::ifstream file("data.csv");
    while (file >> s >> c >> x >> c >> y >> c >> z) {
        t.push_back(s);
        u.push_back(x);
        v.push_back(y);
        w.push_back(z);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And it tooks me in this large CSV (~75MB):

```
real        0m4.766s
user        0m4.660s
sys         0m0.088s
```

C style is more fast!

I'd like to **read a string in the first column (or in the second)** and put into a vector of `std::string`.

I try many possibilites (char *, iostream, etc.) But I can't done in a fast and elegant way.

Examples of types of large CSV files (is there one easier to read than another?):

*a.csv*:

```
hi,3,4.1,5.4
hello,-4,-0.1,-11.3
...
```

*b.csv*:

```
hi 3 4.1 5.4
hello -4 -0.1 -11.3
...
```

*c.csv*:

```
"hi",3,4.1,5.4
"hello",-4,-0.1,-11.3
...
```

*d.csv*:

```
"hi" 3 4.1 5.4
"hello" -4 -0.1 -11.3
...
```

Thank you very much for the help! :)

Comment: I read it over a couple times but I don't really understand what you want. I'm not sure if I'm just slow today or the question is not clear.

Comment: See if there is any difference doing `std::ios_base::sync_with_studio(false)` in the beginning of `main`.

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "c++ read variables file parse" to find many examples.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas Matthews! I find the solution, I'll post it! :)

Comment: But the problem is the buffer for scanf and the slowlyness of C++... :-(

Answer (score 0):

So you're looking for a more efficient way of doing this? Well, one thing you could do is consider whether or not you really need vectors. Depending on your usage, you may be better with some kind of linked list structure.

Comment: Linked list would most likely be way slower than a vector in the use case he showed in his snippets (adding lots of data to the end of the container). And I think his question is more about I/O performance than container, since he uses vectors even in his "C style" version