# Reading csv with fstream, and only fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

I have seen other answers on this matter, but all of them deal with a `std::stringstream`, or a temporary `char` or `std::string` array, various other sorts of external libraries, but I would like to try using only the `fstream` header, to try to read a file that has only numbers, both `char` and `short`, together with `float`, separated by commas, forming more than one lines of text; some may be arrays, or vectors. Example:

```
1,1.1,11.1,11
2,2.2,22.2,22
3,3.3,33.3,33
...
```

The order is known, since each line follows the variables from a `struct`. The number of lines may vary, but, for now, let's assume it is also known. Also for the sake of example, let's only consider this order, and these types:

```
int, double, double, int
```

Going along with a piece of code I have seen, I tried this simplistic (and, most probably, naive) approach:

```
int a, d;
double b, c;
char fileName {"file.txt"};
std::fstream fs {fileName};
if(!fs.is_open())
    // open with fs.out, write some defaults; this works, no need to mention
else
{
    char comma;
    while(fs.getline(fileName, 100, '\n'))
    {
        fs >> a >> comma >> b >> comma >> c >> comma >> d;
        std::cout << 2*a << ", " << 2*b << ", " << 2*c << ", " << 2*d << '\n';
    }
}
```

If the file has the three lines above, plus a terminating `\n`, it outputs this:

```
4, 4.4, 44.4, 44
6, 6.6, 66.6, 66
6, 6.6, 66.6, 66
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I add a `\n` at the beginning of the file, it outputs:

```
2, 2.2, 22.2, 22
4, 4.4, 44.4, 44
6, 6.6, 66.6, 66
6, 6.6, 66.6, 66
```

If I remove the last `\n`, it works as intended. I have a few questions:

1. What else can I do when writing the file besides adding a beginning `\n` and not inserting a terminating one in order to work as intended?
2. If the number of variables is longer, say 100 per line, what can I do to avoid going 'round the Earth with `fs >> a >> c >> ...`?
3. If I only need to read a specific line, or only a few, one method would probably be counting the occurences of `\n`, or the lines, somehow. How could I do that?

(edit)

4. Not lastly, as the title mentions, is it possible to do it without involving other headers, only with `fstream` (as it currently is, for example)?

Comment: You might want to go through your code again. It doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @FeiXiang Thank you for letting me know. I see I reversed two `<<` in the `fs >> ...` line. Is there something else I am missing? (to not edit too many times)

Comment: There was some post which changed locale. Search for it

Comment: @Incomputable I am not sure I follow. I tried now searching for "change locale" and I only get posts relevant to the localization settings. If it's a c++ domain, could you please specify? I am not advanced.

Comment: parsing csv file c++. Use that search string, you should stumble upon an answer which has csv_classification struct.

Comment: I'm sure `while(fs.getline(fileName, 100, '\n'))` isn't what you want. You're repeatedly trying to read a file name from the file into a char array which is likely too small. And your char array isn't an array, but a single char. Why do you even need the char array? Just directly give the file name to the `fstream` constructor. Since you're only doing input, you should use `ifstream` instead. Also, the extraction operator can only read with whitespace as a delimiter. You're going to have to use `getline()` first and then parse it later.

Comment: @FeiXiang I'm afraid that's not it. The char is only there to catch the commas (hence the name). I am using `getline()` to catch the lines of 100 chars, more than enough for this example, and stop at the terminating `\n`. While doing so, it captures the contents of the line (the `fs >> a >> ...` line) directly into the variables defined outside the `while`. As I mentioned, the code works, but not as I expect. Also, the first part of the `if()` says I am using `fs.out` to write defaults. It may be brute and naive, I am admitting, and that's why I am asking for help.

Comment: You are trying to extract a line and put it into the char array called `fileName`, basically discarding a line since you never read from `fileName`.

Comment: @FeiXiang Ah, I see the mistake now. I thought `fileName` is used as the opening file. Is there any way I can avoid using a temporary `char[]`, or `std::string` in there? I'm not fixed on `getline()`.

Comment: There is no way that I know of. Why are you so afraid of it anyway? A few copies won't hurt.

Comment: @FeiXiang It's not only the copies, looking at other examples, all of them use some sort of `char` to `int`, or `double`, etc. The way I did it seemed to work, even as wrong as it were. So, I had hopes...

Comment: @Incomputable It looks like this is the link you were talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224688/csv-parsing-with-c/25225612 . It doesn't answer my question, but it looks like the answer is no. But it does help for the other 3 questions. Maybe together with the other answers I have found, I can concoct some usable code.

Comment: If you know the number and order of the fields, just use a `switch(field_no) { case 0: f >> a >> comma; if (f.eof()) goto done; break;...}`.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen - Do you have any particular *reason* for not using the standard methods [How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c). If you are allergic to stringstreams, you can of course use a temporary disk file instead, but why would anyone want to do that?

Comment: @BoPersson One of the answers I have read (among them your link) said that using `stringstream` can slow down the reading by almost 3 times, I can't find the post, but the example with `fs >> a >> ...` comes from there. So I thought, the simpler, the more efficient. Still, suppose the question 4 is answered (indirectly, 1, too), and it's a no. Because of that I am willing to do it in any of the many ways others have done it, so the other 2 questions remain. I am trying to read and adapt, but I am not a programmer, so I will make mistakes like this one, for example.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Suppose the number of lines is 100, would I have to use a one-hundred-liner `switch`? What if the number of lines varies?

Comment: @BoPersson I found the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778571/fastest-way-to-get-data-from-a-csv-in-c . He uses an intermediary `string`, others a `char` array, others `stringstream`, who knows how many ways are there. Given that most try to find a faster way, I thought maybe I can cut a corner or two.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen - no, the switch is for the known number of fields... I'll drop a short example with your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The order is known, since each line follows the variables from a
>   struct. The number of lines may vary, but, for now, let's assume it is
>   also known. Also for the sake of example, let's only consider this
>   order, and these types:
>
> ```
> int, double, double, int
> ```

If the number and order of the fields is known, then you can simply read with `>>` or `getline` using both the `','` or `'\n'` delimiter as required. While it is much wiser to use *line-oriented input* to read an entire line and then `stringstream` to parse the fields, there is no reason you can't do the same thing utilizing only `fstream` as you have indicated is your goal. It's not as elegant of a solution, but a valid one nonetheless.

**Using the `>>` Operator**

Your data has 4-fields, the first 3 are delimited by a `comma`, the final delimited by the `newline`. You can simply loop continually and read using the `>>` operator and test for `fail()` or `eof()` after each read, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define NFIELD 4
#define MAXW 128

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int a, d;
    double b, c;
    char comma;

    std::fstream f (argv[1]);
    if (!f.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed " << argv[1] << ".\n";
        return 1;
    }

    for (;;) {          /* loop continually */
        f >> a >> comma >> b >> comma >> c >> comma >> d;
        if (f.fail() || f.eof())   
            break;
        std::cout << 2*a << "," << 2*b << "," << 2*c << "," << 2*d << '\n';
        f.ignore (MAXW, '\n');
    }
    f.close();
}
```

Keeping a simple field counter `n`, you can use a simple `switch` statement based on the field number to read the correct value into the corresponding variable, and when all fields are read output (or otherwise store) all 4 values that make up your struct. (obviously you can fill each member at the time they are read as well). Nothing special is required, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define NFIELD 4

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int a, d, n = 0;
    double b, c;
    char comma;

    std::fstream f (argv[1]);
    if (!f.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed " << argv[1] << ".\n";
        return 1;
    }

    for (;;) {          /* loop continually */
        switch (n) {    /* coordinate read based on field number */
            case 0: f >> a >> comma; if (f.eof()) goto done; break;
            case 1: f >> b >> comma; if (f.eof()) goto done; break;
            case 2: f >> c >> comma; if (f.eof()) goto done; break;
            case 3: f >> d; if (f.eof()) goto done; break;
        }
        if (++n == NFIELD) {    /* if all fields read */
            std::cout << 2*a << "," << 2*b << "," << 2*c << "," << 2*d << '\n';
            n = 0;      /* reset field number */
        }
    }
    done:;
    f.close();
}
```

**Example Input File**

Using your provided sample input.

```
$ cat dat/mixed.csv
1,1.1,11.1,11
2,2.2,22.2,22
3,3.3,33.3,33
```

**Example Use/Output**

You obtain your desired output by simply doubling each field on output:

```
$ ./bin/csv_mixed_read dat/mixed.csv
2,2.2,22.2,22
4,4.4,44.4,44
6,6.6,66.6,66
```

(the output for both above is the same)

**Using `getline` Delimited by `','` and `'\n'`**

You can use a slight variation on the logic to employ `getline`. Here, you read the first 3 fields with `f.getline(buf, MAXC, ',')`, and when the 3rd field is found, you read the final field with `f.getline(buf, MAXC)`. For example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#define NFIELD  4
#define MAXC  128

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int a = 0, d = 0, n = 0;
    double b = 0.0, c = 0.0;
    char buf[MAXC];

    std::fstream f (argv[1]);
    if (!f.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed " << argv[1] << ".\n";
        return 1;
    }

    while (f.getline(buf, MAXC, ',')) { /* read each field */
        switch (n) {    /* coordinate read based on field number */
            case 0: a = std::stoi (buf); break;
            case 1: b = std::stod (buf); break;
            case 2: c = std::stod (buf); 
                if (!f.getline(buf, MAXC))  /* read d with '\n' delimiter */
                    goto done;
                d = std::stoi (buf);
                break;
        }
        if (++n == NFIELD - 1) {    /* if all fields read */
            std::cout << 2*a << "," << 2*b << "," << 2*c << "," << 2*d << '\n';
            n = 0;      /* reset field number */
        }
    }
    done:;
    f.close();
}
```

(**note:** unlike using the `>>` operator, when using `getline` as above, there can be no *whitespace* following each `comma`.)

**Example Use/Output**

The output is the same.

```
$ ./bin/csv_mixed_read2 dat/mixed.csv
2,2.2,22.2,22
4,4.4,44.4,44
6,6.6,66.6,66
```

Regardless whether you use something like the examples above, or `stringstream`, you will have to know the number and order of the fields. Whether you use a loop and `if..else if..else` or `switch` the logic is the same. You need some way of coordinating your read with the correct field. Keeping a simple field counter is about as simple as anything else. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: My purpose is to generate a save file for the `struct` holding the input data and various other settings. There are different topics, each requiring the same `struct`. I can reinforce a rule of writing, such as csv, I can determine how many lines to save (nr. of topics), even though it will fill up in time as this will be refreshed after each use. That's why I said it will have a known number of lines and (ordered) values. I find the 1st example very appealing. I don't see on cppreference, but is there an `eol()`, too? Or maybe a way to count the `\n` (I'll probably have to use a `char`)?

Comment: There is no `eol()`, but `f.getline (NCHARS, '\n')` allows for the same test. You can always add a simple `int n = 0;` to the first example and just increment it at the end of each loop. That would count the lines for you. Give it a go. If you have any problems, drop another comment and I'm happy to help.

Comment: Most probably I'll just use all the lines, and fill the unused ones with default values. For finding a certain line I thought of having a string with `{"one", "two", ...}` at the beginning of each line, but I think that will be cumbersome to have to check against strings. Or, looking at cppreference fstream.ignore(), I see I can use that as a way to determine the occurences of `\n`, and make a separate function with a loop. Maybe not beautoful, but working (for now). (Just saw your comment) Thanky you for the help. I'll mark this as the answer, but I may return with comments. :-)

Comment: Sure, that works, but anytime you have the choice between using a simple counter -- or using some other function -- take the counter route and avoid the overhead of a separate function call. (it's minimal, but can add up over a large application...) Also, instead of some number `NCHARS` in `ignore`, the proper constant is to include `<limits>` and use `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` (which is `INT_MAX`) for the number of characters to ignore.

Comment: Then I think a not very bad approach would be to combine them. I can count chars until `\n`, that will be my `MAXC`, use it to `getline()` and `>>` directly in the variables. If I need to only perform actions on certain lines, I can skip to a different `\n` based on an `enum`, or even a string array. Maybe I can even do it without the help of an intermediate `char` array, or `stringstream`, as in your examples. So I can use a loop and avoid `switch`. It starts looking better, and there I thought I would be flayed alive for daring ask such a question, against "the books", by the looks of it.

Comment: Well, there is educational value in figuring out all the different ways you can "skin-a-cat". From it comes an understanding of which coding tool to pickup to handle which coding problem. This is the "nuts-and-bolts" of learning. It's not the most elegant part of coding -- but it darn sure is the most important. A house is only as good as the foundation it is built on...